# Accessing all props in nested propTypes in a React component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to conditionally make lightboxImage required or not based on the property of disableLightbox.  However when i read props from lightboxImage I only get the first level of properties (src, width, height, aspectRatio) and not the level up (photos, disableLightbox).  Is there any way I can read all of the properties?

```js
Gallery.propTypes = {
    photos: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
        React.PropTypes.shape({
            src: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, 
            width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            height: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            aspectRatio: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            lightboxImage: props => console.log(props)
        })  
    ).isRequired,
    disableLightbox: React.PropTypes.bool
};
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add your function (your log method) in your componentDidMount or constructor?

Comment: @CapCa because i need to access the value of the other props there in order to determine whether this prop should be required or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@MatthewHerbst Explained the key idea, a custom validator, but here's a rewritten version of the example code that's more complete and applicable and yet simpler (FYI, untested though):

```js
photos: function (props, propName, componentName) {
  // I don't know what `lightboxImage` is, I'll assume string.
  var lightboxImageValidator = React.PropTypes.string;
  if (!props.disableLightbox) {
    lightboxImageValidator = lightboxImageValidator.isRequired;
  }

  return React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      src: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, 
      width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      height: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      aspectRatio: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      lightboxImage: lightboxImageValidator,
    })  
  ).isRequired.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, much easier to do when acting on `photos` instead of `disableLightbox` :)

Comment: Yeah, perfectly. I just used `disableLightbox` since OP asked about that. I actually like yours a bit better not just because of the simplicity, but because it only does a single pass on `photos` while mine has to do a second pass on `photos`.

Answer (score 3):

While not possible with the standard PropType validators, you *could* do this by writing [a custom validator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation) for either `disableLightbox` or `photos`. Let's do it using `disableLightbox` since that's what you are asking about:

```js
disableLightbox: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  // First, we need to check that we're a Boolean
  // You could do this with PropTypes.boolean but it's much simpler to do it yourself
  let type = typeof props[propName];
  if (type !== 'boolean') {
    return new Error(propName + ' supplied to ' + componentName + ' is of type `' + type +'`. `boolean` expected. Validation failed.');
  }

  if (props[propName]) {
    if (props.hasOwnProperty('photos') {
      // Now we do the fun part. Here we are manually checking the validation of photos
      // using the built-in PropTypes, but this time with lightboxImage required
      let typeChecker = PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        lightboxImage.string.isRequired
      }));

      return typeChecker(props, 'photos', componentName, 'prop');
    } else {
      // Missing the photos prop
      return new Error(propName + ' supplied to ' + componentName + ' has a true value, but prop `photos` is missing. Validation failed.');
    }
  } else {
    // disableLightbox is false, so no need to check lightboxImage
  }
}
```

I highly suggest taking a good read over the custom validator examples in the docs (disclaimer: I wrote the `customArrayProp` example). The example above might be considered slightly hacky, but it should work. You should also note that the above could have a performance impact if `photos` is big, since it's basically running the validation all over again.